# False positive in SonarQube squid:S2583

Tags: java, sonarqube

*Note: the code here is just minimal code to recreate, the code that caused this issue actually involved the `InitialContext` object.*

SonarQube rule squid:S2583,

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

appears to produce false positives when an object is instantiated, even if the constructor throws a checked exception. As a minimal example,

```
public void falsePositive()
{
  TestObject myValue = null;
  try
  {
    myValue = new TestObject();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    if (myValue != null)
    {
      System.out.println("Not null");
    }
  }
}
```

With `TestObject` declared as

```
public class TestObject
{
  public TestObject() throws Exception
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

This produces an issue on the `if (myValue != null)` line, implying that `myValue` is always non-null which is obviously not the case.

Is this a bug in the rule, or am I just missing something here?

Comment: This sounds to be an issue with the try/catch/finally flow. Which version of the plugin are you using ?

Comment: This was running with `sonar-java-plugin-3.8`

Comment: @benzonico I see 3.9 is out - I'll try with it quickly.

Comment: There are still some bugs in 3.9 but this one should be covered by the improvement made.

Comment: Had some incompatibilities of some sort (probably something on our side), but the false positive is definitely gone - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to some flow analysis errors and have been solved in sonar java plugin version 3.9